# Eclipse not finding file

Tags: eclipse, file, input, find

I'm having some trouble locating the text file in my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("args is out of range");
    }

    final String from = args[0];
    final String to = args[1];
    int errCode = 0; // Unix error handling

    // FileReader uses "the default character encoding".
    // To specify an encoding, use this code instead:
    // new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
    // FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));

    // This "try-with-resource" statement automatically calls file.close()
    // just before leaving the try block.
    try (BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("distances.txt"))) { // absolutadressen :C
        pathSearch(from, to, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        errCode = 1;
    } finally {
        System.exit(errCode);
    }
}
```

Everytime I run it, it says "File not found". I've tried replacing "distances.txt" with the adress distances.txt is at. distances.txt is also inside the project folder so I don't understand why it's not being found. If i run the code from the terminal, the file can be found by using its adress, but I would like it to work from eclipse. An alternativ is to be able to place this whole package

Here's a pic of the project

[image: project]

Answer (score 2):

Take it out of the package to the src folder, then use the line below to read it:

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getResource("/distances.txt").getFile()));
```

Comment: I get "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object. I'm running this in my main() method, going to show more code in the original post to clarify.

Comment: @PontusBrink Can you try `Class.class` instead of `getClass()`?

Comment: Worked, but I still get the File not found error :/

Comment: Changed the /distances.txt to \\distances.txt since I am on windows. It's not giving me any errors anymore! It's not doing what's expected, but this problem is solved :) thank you!

Comment: @PontusBrink You're welcome. It's strange since I had written this code on Windows.

Comment: looks like I spoke to soon. It's still not working :/ if I remove the finally block of the try statement, i get a NullPointerException with the "\\". Using "/" gives me the File not found error. I'm extremely confused what's going on.

Comment: @PontusBrink Are you sure that the exception is thrown by this lane? It shouldn't throw `NullPointerException`. Maybe your `pathSearch()` throws it?

Comment: Well, the higlighted section is the BufferedReader one, not pathSearch().